# confusing case of a bash completion script

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble understanding what the following code does in a bash completion script:

```
    case "$last" in
    +\(--import|-i\))
            _filedir '+(txt|html)';;
```

When is that case ever met? I thought the second line above would be something like

```
--import|-i)
```

which does make sense to me. I grepped my `bash_completion.d` directory for `'+\\('` but that one was the only one that came up so I guess it's not that common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is indeed puzzling without context. As it is, it matches two literal strings -

```
$ case "+(--import" in +\(--import|-i\)) echo match ;; esac
match
$ case "-i)" in +\(--import|-i\)) echo match ;; esac
match
```

It looks similar to the extended glob pattern `+(--import|-i)`, but in this form it's neither a match for the literal pattern (would need to escape the pipe) nor the actual pattern (would need to unescape the parentheses). I'd guess "bug", but bash completion is a minefield of crazy metaprogramming, so it's impossible to say without seeing the entire script.

From [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> If  the  extglob  shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the
>   following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one
>   or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
> ```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I cannot post the context, but I don't think it would help. Note that `extglob` is indeed enabled

Comment: No problem, would just have been interesting to see an context where that actually makes sense :)

Comment: Since the body of that particular case appears to pass an actual extended pattern to a function called `_filedir`, I'd guess that `$last` contains part of another extended pattern, rather than text to complete. The code appears to be implementing some sort of transformation rule.